# How can you set Mink output without visting a page?

Tags: php, phpunit, mink

I have a situation where I have a Mink based test where I need to use Mink assertions without actually visiting a URL.  Normally, I would just use the assertions directly on my strings, but I need to xpath on generated output that I can't retrieve from a URL.

As far as I can tell, the `Behat\Mink\Driver\DriverInterface` and `Behat\Mink\Element\DocumentElement` just have methods for getting page content, but setting the page content is done via `private` methods and properties.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't really understand what you need to do, please add few steps of what you are trying to accomplish. As far as I understood you want to check an element in a page without visiting the page, if so you can use file_get_contents to get the page and create a new DOMXPath object that you can query by xpath.